# How does a list comprehension in python avoid side effects?

Tags: python, functional-programming, side-effects

[from python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

We can calculate the list of squares without any side effects using:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

My question is - How is this without side effects ?

the above code also creates (or overwrites) a variable named x that still exists after the loop completes.

Edited : since I've been asked for code samples (this is from python 2.7)

```
x = 0
print "before list comprehension"
print "x = "+str(x)
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
print "after list comprehension"
print "x = "+str(x)
```

Output -

```
before list comprehension
x = 0
after list comprehension
x = 9
```

Comment: Did you try printing `x` after that line of code to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. the value of x changes depending on the argument given to range. In the above case - The value of x was 9

Comment: please post your code where this happens.

Comment: Please post a complete example replicating your observation. The `x` variable exists only within the scope of that comprehension.

Comment: In 2.7 it gives a value of 9 just as he describes.

Comment: @systemjack can you post the code which gave you that example?

Comment: Please read the link I provided. That explains it. You have to be careful what version you are actually using based on the documentation you are reading. You were reading about Python 3 and using a Python 2 interpreter.

Comment: @idjaw Thanks ! I should have been more careful. I've marked the question as a duplicate